# getTimezoneOffset() Method

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs

The `getTimezoneOffset()` method returns the time difference between **UTC time** and **local time** in minutes.

If I am in California and using **PST time** which is 8 hrs behind `(GMT -8)` & `(GMT -7)` during date light saving.

Wasn't `getTimezoneOffset()` method supposed to return `-420min` instead of `420min`?

Answer (score 1):

### No

`getTimezoneOffset()` returns you an offset with respect to your current time, thus if you are trailing, you will get a positive result.

> ### Description
>
> The time-zone offset is the difference, in minutes, between UTC and local time. Note that this means that the offset is positive if the local timezone is behind UTC and negative if it is ahead. For example, if your time zone is UTC+10 (Australian Eastern Standard Time), -600 will be returned. Daylight saving time prevents this value from being a constant even for a given locale.

<sup>source [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset)</sup>

Comment: Check out the example of w3school. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettimezoneoffset.asp

Comment: @user6870671 What is wrong in the linked example on W3Schools? Quoting them, "`For example, If your time zone is GMT+2, -120 will be returned`," which is correct. So in your case you should see a positive value.

Comment: Yes I get positive 420, but that is not producing correct result. I had to subtracted the offset min off of the report time to get the correct time. My question is if my web service is stored California why wasn't getting me the correct result

Comment: @user6870671 - I'm sorry but I'm actually finding it difficult to understand the issue! :) All I can say is that the location of the web server doesn't matter. The offset is a difference between the Current Locale time of the web browser where the JS code is running and UTC, which is constant. Does that help?

Comment: @user6870671 - Thinking about it again, I have a vague idea of what you are saying!

Comment: @user6870671 - You are still wrong in assuming that you shouldn't have to subtract the time to get the local time from UTC. But that is just semantics based on how the original method was defined. The method returns a positive for trailing zones based on its description. A timezone (GMT-x) is defined w.r.t. the GMT/UTC timeline, whereas this function runs on the browser w.r.t. the current locale, hence why in your case it says there is still (+)x mins to go before you get to where UTC is just now. Maybe in your case, this is wrong function to use if you are trying to derive the local time.

Comment: My reports are being generated in the server (e.g: Email server, report server) and being downloaded to the user browser in California. The server is hosted in CA and it is using UTC time. Why should I had to subtract the offset min? Why shouldn't the getTimezoneOffset() method returned -420 min?